# "No module named MyClass" error on PyCharm

Tags: python, syntax, pycharm, underline

I am using PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.1 but when I have two+ python files on the same directory, if I import one of them into the other it gets underlined saying:

```
# main.py
import MyClass1
```

> No module named MyClass1 less... (Ctrl+F1) This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Top-level items are supported better than instance items.

but when I execute my main.py it works properly.

Other regular imports like `import sys` don't get underlined.

Comment: Whats the name of the file holding MyClass1?

Comment: Are these two python files under the same directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If those two python files are under the same directory eg. `MyDirectory`, you need to import the classes using the `MyDirectory` as the root. So for example if you have the below project structure:

```
└── MyDirectory
    ├── file1.py (MyClass1)
    └── file2.py (MyClass2)
```

To import the `MyClass1` into the file2.py you can do it as below:

```
from MyDirectory.file1 import MyClass1
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is because you are not importing correctly.

Python imports follow this syntax.

```
import filename
```

This means you need to have a file name `filename.py` in the current directory. You can also import a specific class from that file like so.

```
from filename import MyCalss
```